# Correct .htaccess for including a parked domain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm sure this has been properly addressed on StackOverflow, but the syntaxes differ from situation to situation, and I want to get it right.

I am serving pages at `xyz.com`, but we also have `xyz.net` parked and *forwarded to* `xyz.com`.  What should I add to my `.htaccess` file to address this?

And also, highlighting my extreme lack of expertise, I'm wondering if there are similar issues with `xyz.com` versus `www.xyz.com`?

Comment: How exactly do you want to address this, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Well, for example, if someone were visiting an unrelated site elsewhere and entered the URL www.xyz.net/gallery, obviously he'd get a 404 because there is no such location.  So for one, I'd like that addressed.  Also we're using a contact form script that seems to have some issues with the presence (or not) of www in the URL.  So I probably need to deal with all such problems.